# Sharepoint 2010 anonymous publishing site - workflows not running

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow

We're working on a publishing site with sharepoint 2010. It allows anonymous access, and these anonymous users can fill out certain forms. The form submission works fine as the anonymous user has permission to insert to the lists.

There is a simple workflow attached to each form that emails the contents of the form to an internal user. This works fine if you add the list item manually (ie logged in as a certain user), but the workflow can't be initiated by an anonymous user. It hangs in progress, then eventually fails.

I tried this:

http://blog.furuknap.net/enabling-declarative-workflows-for-anonymous-users-in-sp20102007

But it didn't seem to work either. Some comments from users refer to this same issue - and no one stated a resolution.

I'm worried that the only solution is the run with elevated privileges on each form as a custom web part.

Any solutions out there?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps described in the mentioned post only work for items added to the list by email. So any items added (new form, new document, new event) added using the sharepoint UI will NOT trigger the workflows. (see the [related MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953289)).

There are 2 things I can think of you could try:

- Use an ItemEventReceiver bound to the list to send the email in the ItemAdded event.
- If all the workflow does is send an email to a user, just have that user subscribe to the list using an alert

Comment: I ended up sending the email through code, as you suggested. Users can't sign up for alerts as they are not part of the domain...